# NuGet 5.x does not work with MSBuild 17.How to update all CI yaml for all projects

Tags: azure-pipelines, devops, tfsbuild

We have probably hundreds of projects in TFS. So, now in TFS I see installed NuGet version 5.x. When we try to install MSBuild 17 (Visual Studio 2022) and build, build is failing with NETSDK1004 error. Which means that Nuget 5.x does not work with MSBuild 17. MSBuild 17 requires Nuget 6.x.

I can update Nuget version to 6.x in the task NuGetToolInstaller@1, but it requires to go through all CI files one by one.
Is there any way that I can make all builds using Nuget 6.x? Maybe some global setting?

Tried this: Installed VS 2022 and attempted to build. Got NETSDK1004.

Comment: *it requires to go through all CI files one by one*. Global search-and-replace? Scripting?